# ASP.NET MVC app does not finish page loading when launched from VS 2022

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2022, iis-express-10

I have a MVC web application for about 7 years in operation. About a month ago I've finished and deployed new version with major layout changes based on Bootstrap 5 template. Yesterday I've published minor updates - the app is running at the production server. Today, needing to make some other updates I'm not able to make the app running at my development PC anymore. The browser started  loading the page, the title is set, but the page loading is not finished. I have tried to step through the layout.cshtml file - went it through completely.

Here is the last part of output of the Debug:

```
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/15/ROOT-1-133233826033764319): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\9c4767f5\86e2386a\App_Web_ojytgbdd.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/15/ROOT-1-133233826033764319): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\9c4767f5\86e2386a\App_Web_bqlj2ah4.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/15/ROOT-1-133233826033764319): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/15/ROOT-1-133233826033764319): Loaded 'C:\Users\marti\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\9c4767f5\86e2386a\App_Web_stdraha3.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/15/ROOT-1-133233826033764319): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Languages\Microsoft.WebTools.Languages.Html.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/15/ROOT-1-133233826033764319): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Languages\Microsoft.WebTools.Languages.Shared.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

The thread 0x6e3c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x7a40 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x14e8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2210 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3f88 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x657c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x8014 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x7f18 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xb94 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x7a50 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2a0c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5c44 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x7ba4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x6ff0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x7e80 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I've tried to change the web browser - MS Edge and Chrome, tried Debug and Release configuration. Still the same result.

When started Without Debugging (Ctrl+F5), page loaded properly.

**EDIT**
Browser Console is empty. The page is loaded partially, because the loading indicator element is displayed.

**EDIT 2**
Looking at the Browser dev tools Network tab I see there are [2 fonts pending for load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOG3s.png)

Comment: Does the browser console show anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, it was solved by disabling the "Script Debugging" option in the Run button detail.